# Ionic 4 ion-datetime floating label always floats even without a value

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Ionic 4, label always floats on an ion-datetime field when no value as follows.

My code

```
<form [formGroup]="statusHandlerForm">
    <ion-item class="input-container " align-items-center no-padding>
      <ion-label position="floating" no-margin no-padding>Date of Loss</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime no-padding formControlName="dateOfLoss" display-format="MMM DD, YYYY"></ion-datetime>
      <ion-icon src="/assets/icon/calendar.svg" color="primary" slot="end"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this *partially*, by dynamically setting the `position` attribute:

```
<ion-label [position]="statusHandlerForm.controls.dateOfLoss.value ? 'floating' : null">Date of Loss</ion-label>
```

This will display the label as placeholder and move it to the floating position as soon as the field gets a value.

**However**, the animation between those two states differs from the regular animation for floating labels.

Hope this helps!

**Full example based on your code:**

```
<form [formGroup]="statusHandlerForm">
    <ion-item class="input-container " align-items-center no-padding>
      <ion-label [position]="statusHandlerForm.controls.dateOfLoss.value ? 'floating' : null" no-margin no-padding>Date of Loss</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime no-padding formControlName="dateOfLoss" display-format="MMM DD, YYYY"></ion-datetime>
      <ion-icon src="/assets/icon/calendar.svg" color="primary" slot="end"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```